# SPFx - Wrong function return current user formatted name

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I'm beginner with TS and promises. I want to know Why function  is returning **empty string**?

[image]

How to format my function to return current user formatted name? The request is executed after the function has been executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to query user profile to get the login name or display name.

It is already available inside the `this.context.pageContext.user` object.

Try and modify the below sample code. You can get the login name, display name as well as email without making a REST call to user profile:

```
public render(): void {
const element: React.ReactElement<any> = React.createElement(
   HelloWorld,
   {
     userLoginName: this.context.pageContext.user.loginName,
     userDisplayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName,
     email : this.context.pageContext.user.email,
     context: this.context
   }
);

 ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```